# Angular service: value lost when view changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a simple Angular app that pulls in data from Instagram. The user enters a hashtag on the index page and then is presented to another page where posts with that hashtag are displayed.

I've tried passing the hashtag that's used as a variable in a service, but when the view is changed the value is overwritten. (I can check the value right after I set it and it's set, but as soon as the page changes I lose the value).

Here's my service:

```
var instagramApp = angular.module('instagramApp')
.factory('feedData', function($rootScope) {
    var config = {};
    return {
        setHashtag: function (x) {
                config.hashtag = x;
        },
        getHashtag: function () {
            return config.hashtag;
        }
    }
});
```

And my two controllers:

Sets hashtag (the /index.html view):

```
instagramApp.controller('indexController', ['$scope', 'feedData', '$window',
function($scope, feedData, $window){

$scope.generate = function(){
    feedData.setHashtag('marcheet');
    console.log(feedData.getHashtag());
    $window.location.href = '/results.html';
};

}]);
```

Gets hashtag (the /results.html view):

```
instagramApp.controller('instagramController', ['$scope', 'Instagram', '$http', 'feedData',
function($scope, Instagram, $http, feedData){

    feedUrl = '/feed/?hashtag=' + feedData.getHashtag() +'&count=20';
    console.log(feedUrl);
    createStoryJS({
      type:       'timeline',
      width:      '800',
      height:     '600',
      source:     feedUrl,
      embed_id:   'my-timeline'
    });
}
]);
```

Comment: $window.location.href = '/results.html'; this line right here, you've just left your angular app and so that's why it doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @pcguru, when you run this line `$window.location.href = '/results.html';` your angular app gets reloaded by the browser.

Angular detects changes in the url when the user clicks on links on the page or through setting `$location.path('/someurl');` (which is an angular service for [getting/setting url information](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)). Your javascript circumvents that.

Note the [Angular docs on $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

> What does it [$location] not do?
>
> It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed.
>   To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API,
>   $window.location.href.

If you want to programmatically change the url, use `$location.path(url)`, if you want the user to click a link and go to a new location in the app without the browser reloading the page then you need to setup routing using `angular-route.js` (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.js) and then injecting `$routeProvider` into the config method of your app

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('instagramApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(configFunc);

    function configFunc($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider.when('/', {
             templateUrl: 'path/to/your/template.html',
             controller: 'HomeController'
         })
         .when('/results', {
             templateUrl: 'path/to/your/template.html',
             controller: 'ResultsController'
         });
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Angular's router to handle the location change. That way you will not reload the entire app from scratch when you go to your details view.

[See angular's route documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).

Answer (score 0):

AS saided by @pcguru, you need to use [angular Router](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) OR  [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to keep the context of your single Angular Page.

AngularRouter is part of Angular framework and is simple to use.
Ui-Router is a complement, it is much more costimizable and allows you to use multiple views at the same time. IF you start angular, this is probably not necessary to add extra complexity.

Using something like that  `$window.location.href = '/results.html';` will perform a page redirection and therefore will reload you page.
This is not the way to do it in angular